# Eclipse Oxygen greyed out all the debugging buttons

Tags: eclipse

I would like to know what is the configuration setting such that the debugging buttons on Eclipse Oxygen menu bar will appear normal.  The buttons are the steps into, steps over, steps return etc.

It is very strange that the buttons are all greyed out and no matter how I set the debug configuration, it just won't appear or if it appears(which I did a number of change to settings I can't remember) it will disappear whenever I re-start Eclipse IDE.

Hope someone can tell me the steps to make it normal again.

I am running Tomcat server, dynamic web app with JPA and hibernate and JEE with jsp and Mysql 5.7 in windows 10

Million thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the User group in Tomcat, they have taught me the right way to debug an app.

First, You need to start the Tomcat server.  Configure your app to switch to debug mode when you want to debug.

Also, you need to configure your Tomcat run-time by putting the below at the Argument tab at the Debug configuration of Tomcat.  Right-click your project, Debug As, Debug configuration.

```
   -Dcatalina.base="C:\Users\YourUserName\workspace5\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-tomcat-8.5.24" -Dwtp.deploy="C:\Users\YourUserName\workspace5\.metadata\.plugins
```